# Selecting multiple values in LOV popup in Oracle APEX 4.2

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I current making a pop up list in Oracle APEX 4.2 for someone to choose who their sender is for an email template. The current Popup LoV item only allows the user to select one value. Does anyone know, if possible, is there a way to allow the Popup to be able to select more than one value at once?

I have checked http://www.apex-plugin.com/oracle-apex-plugins/item-plugin/skillbuilders-super-lov_75.html, but this only displays multiple columns.

The current sample code I'm using is:

```
 select EMAIL as display_value, EMAIL as return_value 
 from EMAIL_SURVEY
 order by 1
```

Comment: Check out Select2 - allows multiple selections and works nicely - http://apex-plugin.com/oracle-apex-plugins/item-plugin/select2_344.html

Comment: Select2 is great and highly customizable. The only other alternative is to code your own LOV.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "List Manager" Item instead of the "Popup List of Values (LOV)". It won't be pop up anymore, but I use them often anyway.